# Rules addressing the correct order when multiple objectives modifying a noun

Tags: grammar

I see many examples on the web for multiple objectives modifying a noun. I am wondering if there are some consolidating rules for the order of those objectives.

For example:

> that hungry, tired, sleepy little match girl

Can it be "that tired, hungry, sleepy little match girl" or "that tired, sleepy, hungry little match girl"? Or some other alternative orders?

Some other examples:

> 1. a beautiful new black Italian leather jacket
> 2. an old large brick dining hall

Are these orders fixed? Or they could be changed to some other orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a number of adjectives are used together, the order depends on the function of the adjective. The usual order is:

**Quantity, Value/opinion, Size, Temperature, Age, Shape, Colour, Origin, Material**

However, it is important to note that this order of adjectives before a noun is **not fixed**. You may find slight variations to this , however, this is the generally followed and accepted order.

[Order of Adjectives](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-order)

Coming to the example sentence

> that hungry, tired, sleepy little match girl

Other variations such as, "that tired, hungry, sleepy little match girl" or "that tired, sleepy, hungry little match girl" are also correct. As all these adjectives denote an *opinion* on the state of the girl.

In some other cases however, the ordering can cause the meaning of a sentence to change completely

For e.g.

> A big black American horse - Correct
>
> A black American big horse - Incorrect
>
> An American big black horse - Incorrect

That being said, the "Adjective Ordering Restrictions" is still very much a topic of research and there is no hard and fast *rule*. The existing rule is an observation of how the native speakers handle them.

If you want to read further on this topic, here is a [paper by Alexandra Teodorescu](http://www.lingref.com/cpp/wccfl/25/paper1473.pdf)

Comment: What about the example in my question “Can it be "that tired, hungry, sleepy little match girl" or "that tired, sleepy, hungry little match girl"? ” Are these two variations correct?

Comment: @dan In this example scenario this is correct. I have updated my answer to add some points, hopefully they prove useful